# TensorFlow Speech Emotion Recognition Model gives same prediction for all inputs

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, audio-recognition

Dataset used: [RAVDESS](https://zenodo.org/record/1188976) (I've only used the audio only files)

Here's a sample after I've processed the data:
[image]

And the code for the label encoding:

```
#encode labels as ints
lb = LabelEncoder()

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(lb.fit_transform(y_train))
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(lb.fit_transform(y_test))

#Not sure if this is needed
x_train =np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=2)
x_test= np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=2)
```

Model:

```
    model.add(Conv1D(16, 5,strides=2 ,padding='same', input_shape=(259,1)))
    model.add(Conv1D(16, 5,padding='same', activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(6)))
    model.add(LSTM(1))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(10, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(10,activation="softmax"))
    
    model.summary()
    
    opt = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.00001, decay=1e-6)

    model.compile(metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy')

    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1,epochs=15, validation_data=(x_train, y_train))
```

When I call model.predict() with the test data the model gives the same exact answer for all the inputs. I have 10 classes so the accuracy basically always plateaus at 0.1399 or somewhere similar.

Here's a sample of what my model.predict() returns:
[image]

I've played around with the model for quite a bit now, but I just can't get these results to change.

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: How did you get those 259 columns of input features?

Comment: Is this limited to just the speech samples from RAVDESS?

Comment: You must use a separate split for validation for it to have any value. Proper splitting here would be based on actor, otherwise the task may be too easy.

Comment: Your learning rate is extremely low. How does the training over epochs look like (with fixed validation data?)